# Atan2 table c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to calculate the angles of two points in 2D space. It works with the following:

```
double angle;
x = player->x - x;
z = player->z - y;

angle = atan2 (x, y);
angle *= (180.0 / M_PI);
if(angle < 0) angle += 360;
if(angle >= 360) angle -= 360;

return angle;
```

However I want to use a table for better results:

```
x = player->x - x;
z = player->y - y;

return atanTable[x+32][y+32];
```

With init:

```
int xp = -32;
int yp = -32;
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++, xp++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++, yp++){
        double angle;

        angle = atan2 (xp, yp);
        angle *= (180.0 / M_PI);
        if(angle < 0) angle += 360;
        if(angle >= 360) angle -= 360;
        atanTable[x][y] = angle;
    }
```

The angle is only calculated for values -32 to 32 for x and y.

The table is not properly produced however. I get values of only around 359 and 0, while I should get a range of 0 to 360 degrees.

Am I misusing atan2 somehow?

Comment: Why don't you print out some intermediate values to find out?  Or try some easy test-cases, like something that should produce 90 or 45 degrees,

Comment: A 2D array looks like overkill. The value of atan is determined by (x/y) except when y = 0, in which case `atan` is determined by the sign of x.

Comment: @Msalters: `atan` does not distinguish between theta and theta+pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `yp` within the first loop, not before it.

```
int xp = -32;
for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++, xp++)
{
    int yp = -32; // Note, needs to be reset each time x changes.
    for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++, yp++)
    {
```

Comment: @RobotRock: We've all been there... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nit: atan2() returns an angle in [-pi,pi] always.  Your second if statement is redundant.  It's also likely a bad design: very often you want to test later on for angles in [pi,2pi], which can be done with a simple <0 for the default range.  Basically, atan2() is your friend, the reason the function exists is to save you from the hassle of doing modular math on angles.